# How to active scene2d simple moveTo on it?? libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

How to active scene2d simple move on it?? libgdx

My code like this, but I want to apply scene2d simple moveto code on it

```
public Mario(World world, PlayScreen screen){
    super(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("little_mario"));

    this.world = world;
    defineMario();
    marioStand = new TextureRegion(getTexture(),0,11,16,16);
    setBounds(0,0,16/ MarioBros.PPM, 16 / MarioBros.PPM);
    setRegion(marioStand);

}
```

Doing simple moveto feature

```
public Mario(World world, PlayScreen screen){
    super(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("little_mario"));

    this.world = world;
    defineMario();
    marioStand = new TextureRegion(getTexture(),0,11,16,16);
    setBounds(0,0,16/ MarioBros.PPM, 16 / MarioBros.PPM);
    setRegion(marioStand);

    stage = new Stage(); 
    stage.addActor(this);//Error

    this.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.moveTo(500,500,0.5f)));//Not Work

}
```

Anyidea to make Moveto scene2D function ????

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a Stage that is nowhere. For this Stage to work, you must tie it to a Screen and call act() and draw().